# Using OpenCV, is it possible to find a BoundingRect around an irregular shaped object?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0, android

I am learning to use OpenCV4Android. I know that in order to get a bounding *Rectangle* of a contour, we use the method [`Imgproc.boundingRect()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#boundingrect). But what if I have the contour around an object which can be any shape, like a circle, a semi-circle, a polygon or even an irregular shaped blob.

Can I get that blob separated out from the rest of the image, such that *no* parts of the image area surrounding the blob are included in it? Is it possible? If so, how? What are relevant functions?

Comment: boundingRECT is always a rectangular bounding box of an object or of a contour. What you mean is the contour itself?!? use findContours to get the contour. In the end, what do you want to achieve? You could draw a mask for example. Or you could create an image with alpha channel and copy your object to it, so that everything in the image that is not your object, will not be displayed (if the client - like a browser or an image viewer - supports alpha channel)

Comment: @Micka Even if it doesn't support alpha channel a common background colour like white can be used

Comment: @Micka The ultimate goal is to detect a blob of a certain color (say blue) in an image, and then calculate and display (to the user) the H, S and V channels of the _average_ color of the blob.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder yes you are right, I think I misunderstood the question to not include anything around the object (but in fact it was asked to just not include parts of the original image). So the way is: 1. extract contour 2. draw filled mask on black background. 3. copy masked image (=object) to an "empty" image and maybe crop that image (or copy the subimage)

Comment: @Micka How I have thought to go about it is (1) Detect the colored blob (2)Find its contours (3) Draw a _*boundingWhateverShape*_ around it (3)Separate out this _*boundingWhatever*_ from the rest of the image by `myMat.submat(detectedBlobRoi)`(4)Find the average HSV color of this blob

Comment: @Micka Now the problem with the _Rectangle_ is that, say the detected color-blob is a polygon, so the boundingRect found will contain/include some area of the image background surrounding the blob. These pixels (which are not inside the colored blob) will effect the _average_ value of HSV found for this blob. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: just draw the found contour on a mask image and compute the average value for masked regions only. openCV has mask support for many functions.

Comment: OK I am going to do google search on key steps you listed. But can you tell me one thing (because I had already been looking for a way before this): You said, "So the way is: 1. extract contour..." - Assuming that by "extract contour", you mean to separate out the contour from the image such that no _other_ parts of the image are a part of this Mat (of the contour), is there a way to do that except doing `boundingRect()` and then `submat()`?